# I can't get vlc to play from where it left off in windows 10

Tags: playback

I'm unable to get vlc to resume a video from where it was previously stopped in the playlist. It always starts at the beginning of the play list.

Comment: I think that's how playlists are supposed to work. Try outside of a playlist.

Comment: I should do it if you don't quit & reload in between. VLC's playlisting hasn't quite caught up to everything else yet on saving its current state through quit.This is most noticeable on Mac where it's the expected action these days.

Answer (score 0):

VLC has an option for resume, that is found in menu
*Tools > Preferences > Interface tab*, called "Continue playback?".
Check if it is not by any chance set to "Never".

If this doesn't help in your case, try the VLC Extension of
[vlcTADED](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154008/),
reported as still working 10 months ago, which is described as
"save playlist position+resume".
Read well its description and especially its limitations,
then try it to see if it answers your needs.